# How to create tcp load balancer in GCP with java sdk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created the http load balancer in GCP via java sdk because I was able to find the relevant documentation but for the tcp load balancer I am actually struggling, since I could not find any documentation.

I am referring this document for load balancer.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get?hl=en_US

Comment: Can you share the link for the JAVA SDK for HTTP Load Balancers? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/apis#target_proxies

Comment: Can you share the code that you use and the dependencies version?

Comment: The link that you provided is not the Java SDK. Your link is the REST API which is the same API that I provided.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get?hl=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document which you’re referring to basically depicts REST API in JSON format.
Anyhow, there is no REST API for creating a load balancer itself, however there are REST APIs to create various components (like backend services, forwarding rules) that are constituents of a TCP load balancer. Refer to [this](https://octopus.com/docs/runbooks/runbook-examples/gcp/create-nlb) link for the necessary steps and templates to set up the said configuration.